# Test wait to VideoView finish to start new activity robolectric 3

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I must test a screen splash that have a video, the video duration is 11 seconds when the video finish start a other activity.

I have the follow test class:

```
public class ScreenSplashTest {

  private ShadowActivity screenSplash;
  private ShadowVideoView videoView;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
      ScreenSplash screenSplashActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(ScreenSplash.class).create().get();
      screenSplash = Shadows.shadowOf(screenSplashActivity);
      VideoView videoViewWidget = (VideoView)screenSplash.findViewById(R.id.videoViewSplash);
      videoView = Shadows.shadowOf(videoViewWidget);
  }

  @Test
  public void activityStarts_VideoStartsToPlay() throws Exception{
      assertTrue(videoView.isPlaying());
  }
  @Test
  public void whenVideoFinish_StartsChooseTeamActivity() throws Exception{
      videoView.stopPlayback();
      Intent nextActivity = screenSplash.getNextStartedActivity();
      assertEquals(nextActivity.getComponent().getClassName(), ChooseTeamActivity.class.getName());
  }
}
```

And this is my ScreenSplash activity:

```
public class ScreenSplash extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_splash);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(0xffffff);

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoViewSplash);

        Uri videoFile = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splash);
        videoView.setVideoURI(videoFile);

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChooseTeamActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        videoView.start();
    }
  }
```

The question is how can I write a test for this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener from the getOnCompletionListener of the ShadowVideoView and then call its onCompletion method. You can mock the MediaPlayer object.
A possible code snippet:

```
     assertTrue(videoView.isPlaying());
     MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener completionListener = videoView.getOnCompletionListener();
     completionListener.onCompletion(mock(MediaPlayer.class));
     Intent intent = screenSplash.getNextStartedActivity();
     assertNull(intent);
     assertEquals(ChooseTeamActivity.class.getName(), intent.getComponent().getClassName());
```

This approach will be able to test the above code. If you are thinking of actual complete playback of the video and then execution of listener code, then such approach will not be according to unit test methodology. We test the functionality of written code and not the underlying framework. 
In this case, your test code should test for a valid URI, check if its playing or not and whether the listener performs the required actions.
To test the listener through the MediaPlayer object will also be the test of underlying android code and not just your code.

Comment: ohh thak you :) I very noob to unit testing thaks for the guidance